# FFMPEG mp4 instead of flv

Tags: video, ffmpeg

really struggling with ffmpeg at the moment, after a few days of messing about with it i have managed to get it to almost do what i want!

I have an audio track and a series of images that are to be converted into a slideshow displaying each image for 5 seconds.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i C:\ffmpeg\image-%02d.bmp -i C:\ffmpeg\music.mp3 -qscale:v 2
  -shortest -codec:a copy C:\ffmpeg\output.flv
```

I can get this to work as a flv but not as any other format. I need to have it in either an mp4, avi, wmv, or mov format.

I can convert this to a wmv but the file size is HUGE (about 100meg/min)!

```
ffmpeg -i C:\ffmpeg\output.flv -vcodec wmv1
  -acodec adpcm_ima_wav C:\ffmpeg\output.wmv
```

Can anyone please help me either

- output the original code to mp4,wmv,mov,or avi (with a reasonable file size
  ideally less than 10 meg per min)
- convert the flv to either an mp4,wmv,mov, or avi with again a reasonable
  file size)

Answer (score 0):

I see no issues here

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i %02d.bmp -i 1_Les_Nuits.mp3 -qscale:v 2 -shortest
  -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

Comment: It compiles fine, and the audio plays - but the video plays all except the last frame really fast in the first few frames (<1second) and stays on the last frame for 5 seconds.  take a look- http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x112npw